# error using selenium chromedriver on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I'm having trouble running Selenium with chromeDriver on Windows 7. I'm getting the following error:

```
Jan 27, 2016 11:52:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: 
Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "C:\testproject\target\resources\chromedriver.exe" 
(in directory "."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)
```

Double clicking the driver outside of eclipse gives a windows error (not a valid Win32 application)

Is there some trick to getting it to work on a 64bit Windows 7 environment?

Comment: I should have said "Double clicking the driver outside of eclipse *also* gives a windows error".

Comment: And the code that causes the error (in Java) is: new ChromeDriver();, when using the path:  "webdriver.chrome.driver" and the driver chromedriver.exe off the site:  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded ChromeDriver for Windows and not the one for Linux? And that it was downloaded/unzipped correctly?

Comment: yes definitely was right version.  I think now the download may have gotten corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the ChromeDriver download was corrupted by a network error or something, so the chromedriver.exe is incomplete! Try downloading ChromeDriver again from https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Comment: I revisited this and think that may be the problem

Comment: Thanks alot man , this really solved the problem i was stuck in a very urgent project, Thanks a ton man.

Answer (score 1):

**Killing chromedriver.exe instances** from *command prompt* worked for me.

Before deleting current chromedriver and installing new .exe, you can try executing

```
Taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of reading around, it seems the ChromeDriver executable needs to be on your `PATH`. It's not enough to just point `webdriver.chrome.driver` at it, as presumably other processes need to be able to find it.

See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started (under *"Help WebDriver find the downloaded ChromeDriver executable"*), also https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/0.1/setup-chrome.html.

Comment: You can also start the Selenium server with a param pointing to the ChromeDriver: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error today, before today the selenium run correctly. I find this error is caused by my computer antivirus software, after closing antivirus software all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error due to properties file not exists as i am using it to store ChromeDriver.exe path.