# pycharm-selenium-python: Unable to start chromedriver service - [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

This question is not a duplicate of 
[error using selenium chromedriver on windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025685/error-using-selenium-chromedriver-on-windows-7-64-bit)  as I have tried all solutions mentioned there.

In directory `env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`, considering the following code in `function start`

```
cmd = [self.path]
            cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                            close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                            stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
```

The value for cmd is: `<class 'list'>: ['chromedriver', '--port=58808']`

Within `../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/subprocess.py` function `__init__`

```
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                                pass_fds, cwd, env,
                                startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
                                p2cread, p2cwrite,
                                c2pread, c2pwrite,
                                errread, errwrite,
                                restore_signals, start_new_session)
```

`args` is the only argument passed with value `<class 'list'>: ['chromedriver', '--port=58999']`

But it raises an exception: `[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

This prevents starting of the chromedriver service.

So I changed the `args` to `absolute_path_to_chrome_driver\\chromedriver`:

```
self._execute_child(args, 'absolute_path_to_chrome_driver\\chromedriver', preexec_fn, close_fds,
                                    pass_fds, cwd, env,
                                    startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
                                    p2cread, p2cwrite,
                                    c2pread, c2pwrite,
                                    errread, errwrite,
                                    restore_signals, start_new_session)
```

But it still raises the same exception: `[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

This preventing the launch of chromedriver.

I even downloaded the latest version of chromedriver but  ChromeDriver 2.43 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_win32.zip) but the error persists.

Any clues on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the `chromedriver.exe` needs to be placed in the `..\env\Scripts` folder for this to work - specifying any system path entry did not work here.

When I place anything in over here, I can directly access it by process name. But i cannot use a listed path in system environment variables (or maybe I can but not aware how to :( ).